# How to represent real users and other apis with OAuth?

Tags: api, oauth

I have an API which I'd like to secure using OAuth. My API is accessed with a web frontend used by real human users all with their own account (a couple of thousand), and it is also used by the API of some partner companies (less than a hundred), which should also have separate accounts.

[image: Diagram illustrating the users of the API]

I would like to secure the API using OAuth, and I have to decide how to represent the different users. In OAuth, there are two different concepts, clients and users, where client is the higher level concept, and every user is under one of the clients.

I can think of two different ways to represent these API accounts:

- Have a single **client**, and have a separate **user** for every human user, and for every partner API.
- Have one **client** for the human users, and a separate **user** for every human user. And have a separate **client** for every partner API.

Which of the two approaches would be the more idiomatic approach in OAuth? From a technical standpoint I don't see too much advantage or disadvantage of either solution.

(I'm partly confused because the *client credential flow* is described to be used for API-to-API authentication, which seems to make sense for authenticating the partner APIs. However, most of the OAuth guides also say that it should only be used for *trustful* APIs (whatever that means), or even internal APIs, but these partner APIs are definitely not internal.)

Answer (score 1):

Implementation will be unified if there is separate client behind every app (including JS one, for users accessing your API via web frontend).
Also it will be possible to manage ACL per app in this case, which will define maximum privileges for the users (users may choose to give less privileges to the app).

On the other hand, simpler approach is to use Cookies for web frontend users and OAuth for partner applications. But in this case you need to support both authentication options.